# Directus dashboard information not available by REST API

Tags: directus

I want to get the numbers in a panel inside a dashboard. I used 'http://localhost:8055/panels/25c85ee7-a85d-4bbe-b00a-c2b125e38793' and got this response:

````
  "data": {
    "id": "25c85ee7-a85d-4bbe-b00a-c2b125e38793",
    "dashboard": "bb51de5f-bf0b-49d2-a11d-5e74814f6d8c",
    "name": null,
    "icon": null,
    "color": null,
    "show_header": false,
    "note": null,
    "type": "list",
    "position_x": 1,
    "position_y": 15,
    "width": 15,
    "height": 15,
    "options": {
      "collection": "payment",
      "sortField": null,
      "displayTemplate": "{{amount}}",
      "linkToItem": true
    },
    "date_created": "2023-04-19T08:06:56.703Z",
    "user_created": "2e7fd8ab-e700-49e7-aa12-09a885d1fd42"
  }
}```

But this lacks the most important data which are the numerical metrics in a panel. Is there any way to get this data in a response?
````